# ListView start from bottom of list

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm building a chat app and I want to achieve a `ListView()` that loads up like its reverse property is set to true i.e showing the end of the ListView on build. The reason I don't want to set the reverse property to true is because, if the items in the ListView do not fill up the screen, they are aligned to the bottom (cannot use shrinkWrap because of performance), and also because it reverses the order of the items and to show new elements at the bottom of the list, I'd need to use a spread operator and I'm worried about performance since the Map from which I render from can grow significantly.

I have also tried using the ScrollController's jumpTo method inside a `SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback` but the user can see the scrolling and
it also causes it to jump like it's attempting to scroll beyond what is contained in the ListView. I have also used `ScrollablePositionedList` and set the index to which I want to scroll, but this jumps also.

Is there any way I can achieve my aim without any drawbacks visually or performance-wise?

Answer (score 1):

You have the correct idea: in the `initState`, jump to the end. The end of the list can be obtained from `position.maxScrollExtent`. When done correctly, this does not create any visual or performance drawbacks. For example:

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      _controller.jumpTo(_controller.position.maxScrollExtent);
    });
  }
```

The `_controller` should be the `ScrollController` passed to the list.